# How to execute asyncronously inside an Arrow + Reactor Monad comprehension

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor, arrow-kt

In he following piece of code, every `helloX()` method runs asynchronously (it's a deferred Mono that runs in a separate thread), see full code  below):

```
    override fun helloEverybody(): Kind<ForMonoK, String> {
        return MonoK.monad().fx.monad {
            val j = !helloJoey()
            val j2 = !helloJohn()
            val j3 = !helloMary()
            "$j and $j2 and $j3"
        }.fix()
    }
```

However in the logs I see that they are run secuentially:

```
14:10:46.983 [main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers$LoggerFactory - Using Slf4j logging framework
14:10:47.084 [elastic-2] INFO com.codependent.kotlinarrow.service.HelloServiceImpl - helloJoey()
14:10:49.087 [elastic-2] INFO com.codependent.kotlinarrow.service.HelloServiceImpl - helloJoey() - ready
14:10:49.090 [elastic-3] INFO com.codependent.kotlinarrow.service.HelloServiceImpl - helloJohn()
14:10:54.091 [elastic-3] INFO com.codependent.kotlinarrow.service.HelloServiceImpl - helloJohn() - ready
14:10:54.092 [elastic-2] INFO com.codependent.kotlinarrow.service.HelloServiceImpl - helloMary()
14:10:59.095 [elastic-2] INFO com.codependent.kotlinarrow.service.HelloServiceImpl - helloMary() - ready
hello Joey and hello John and hello Mary
```

How could I make them execute in parallel and aggregate all the results in the monad comprehension once all of them have finished?

Full code with main method():

```
class HelloServiceImpl : HelloService<ForMonoK> {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    override fun helloEverybody(): Kind<ForMonoK, String> {
        return MonoK.monad().fx.monad {
            val j = !helloJoey()
            val j2 = !helloJohn()
            val j3 = !helloMary()
            "$j and $j2 and $j3"
        }.fix()
    }

    override fun helloJoey(): Kind<ForMonoK, String> {
        return Mono.defer {
            logger.info("helloJoey()")
            sleep(2000)
            logger.info("helloJoey() - ready")
            Mono.just("hello Joey")
        }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic()).k()
    }

    override fun helloJohn(): Kind<ForMonoK, String> {
        return Mono.defer {
            logger.info("helloJohn()")
            sleep(5000)
            logger.info("helloJohn() - ready")
            Mono.just("hello John")
        }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic()).k()
    }

    override fun helloMary(): Kind<ForMonoK, String> {
        return Mono.defer {
            logger.info("helloMary()")
            sleep(5000)
            logger.info("helloMary() - ready")
            Mono.just("hello Mary")
        }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic()).k()
    }

}

fun main() {
    val countDownLatch = CountDownLatch(1)
    HelloServiceImpl().helloEverybody().fix().mono.subscribe {
        println(it)
        countDownLatch.countDown()
    }
    countDownLatch.await()
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've adapted the method to combine a sequential operation with a parallel one:

```
    override fun helloEverybody(): Kind<ForMonoK, String> {
        return MonoK.async().fx.async {
            val j = helloJoey().bind()
            val j2= Dispatchers.IO
                    .parMapN(helloJohn(), helloMary()){ it1, it2 -> "$it1 and $it2" }
            "$j and $j2"
        }
    }
```

Unfortunatelly parMapN can'be be used with ForMonoK:

```
Type inference failed: fun <A, B, C, D> CoroutineContext.parMapN(fa: Kind<ForIO, A>, fb: Kind<ForIO, B>, fc: Kind<ForIO, C>, f: (A, B, C) -> D): IO<D>
cannot be applied to
receiver: CoroutineDispatcher  arguments: (Kind<ForMonoK, String>,Kind<ForMonoK, String>,Kind<ForMonoK, String>,(String, String, String) -> String)
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flatMap`, same as `map`, don't have thread semantics or parallelism. What you're after is called `parMap` and `parTraverse`, which runs several `MonoK` in parallel.

At that point the `fx` block becomes innecessary, as it's designed for sequential operations. You can mix and match both.

```
MonoK.async().fx.async {

  val result = 
    Dispatchers.IO
     .parMap(helloJoey(), helloMary()) { joe, mary -> ... }
     .bind()

  otherThing(result).bind()

}
```

Comment: I've tried mixing both a sequential and parallel operations. However parMapN is expecting a ForIO instead of a ForMonoK... ??? See updated question

Comment: That extfun may only be defined for IO, you're right. This is what you're after: https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow-fx/blob/master/arrow-fx/src/main/kotlin/arrow/fx/typeclasses/ParApplicative.kt#L13

I believe we don't have the Concurrent instances for Reactor, so it may be that you'll need to use Reactor's operators for parallelism instead.